# Import WooCommerce Products with Custom Meta Dynamic Pricing Rules

Tags: excel, wordpress, csv, woocommerce

I have an excel file with quantity and price columns which I'm using to create the necessary output for the plugin `WooCommerce Dynamic Pricing`'s pricing rules.

I have almost figured this out, but the WooCommerce importer is wrapping my meta value with it's own `s:1:"...";`. Inside the `...` is the correct value that determines my product's pricing rules (price ranges with fixed price discount). If I manually delete the wrapper, it works. The problem is that I have 1500+ products. **How can I import exactly the value I have in my CSV?**

The `meta: _pricing_rules` column has output that looks like this:

```
a:1:{s:17:"set_9jhpu8nb76h30";a:8:{s:15:"conditions_type";s:3:"all";s:10:"conditions";a:1:{i:1;a:2:{s:4:"type";s:8:"apply_to";s:4:"args";a:1:{s:10:"applies_to";s:8:"everyone";}}}s:9:"collector";a:1:{s:4:"type";s:7:"product";}s:4:"mode";s:10:"continuous";s:9:"date_from";s:0:"";s:7:"date_to";s:0:"";s:5:"rules";a:5:{i:1;a:4:{s:4:"from";s:3:"100";s:2:"to";s:3:"249";s:4:"type";s:11:"fixed_price";s:6:"amount";s:4:"3.65";}i:2;a:4:{s:4:"from";s:3:"250";s:2:"to";s:3:"499";s:4:"type";s:11:"fixed_price";s:6:"amount";s:4:"3.55";}i:3;a:4:{s:4:"from";s:3:"500";s:2:"to";s:3:"999";s:4:"type";s:11:"fixed_price";s:6:"amount";s:4:"3.46";}i:4;a:4:{s:4:"from";s:4:"1000";s:2:"to";s:4:"2499";s:4:"type";s:11:"fixed_price";s:6:"amount";s:4:"3.36";}i:5;a:4:{s:4:"from";s:4:"2500";s:2:"to";s:0:"";s:4:"type";s:11:"fixed_price";s:6:"amount";s:4:"3.27";}}s:10:"blockrules";a:1:{i:1;a:5:{s:4:"from";s:0:"";s:6:"adjust";s:0:"";s:4:"type";s:16:"fixed_adjustment";s:6:"amount";s:0:"";s:9:"repeating";s:2:"no";}}}}
```

Comment: You're calling that a `.CSV`?  A key part of a comma separated values files is commas.  :-)   Looks like a weird offshoot of JSON.

Comment: Oh I think I see - you probably used [this page](https://www.xadapter.com/setting-up-product-import-export-plugin-for-woocommerce/#export-products) to export to CSV, and you probably live somewhere that the Delimiter defaults to a `;`?  ... except that it's still not actual CSV if it has all those {curly braces}.  Maybe there's a better export option under "mapping files"?

Comment: I think it's safe to say you're exporting it incorrectly, since if you go to [this link](https://www.xadapter.com/setting-up-product-import-export-plugin-for-woocommerce/#product-import-export) and check out their two Sample CSV Links, they don't look anything like your data.

Comment: My .csv has all the official columns such as name, description, regular price, etc formatted correctly. I'm specifically talking about a meta product attribute/value that is used by the plugin `WooCommerce Dynamic Pricing` which takes that JSON looking object to interpret it's pricing rules. In my excel file, each product has a column for the `meta: _pricing_rules` that correctly outputs the rules for the products. The problem is with the importer in WooCommerce that adds the extra `s:99:` before the rule in the database.

Answer (score 2):

The values are being double-serialized on import. [This is by design in WordPress.](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/12930#comment:10) When saving post or object meta WordPress will serialize and unserialize objects and arrays automatically. However, sometimes developers (mis)use the Metadata API and try to handle serialization manually. To maintain backwards compatibility with these developers and their code the Metadata API will return any serialized value exactly as it was passed in. To accomplish this the value stored in the database must be wrapped in the `s:99:"..."` format.

The work around is to ensure WooCommerce imports unserialized values when saving product meta.

The `woocommerce_product_importer_parsed_data` filter along with the [`maybe_unserialize`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/maybe_unserialize) function can be used to conditionally unserialize meta values to arrays/objects. The Metadata API will then store these fields without the double-serialization.

```
<?php

// Step through import meta fields.
// Use `maybe_unserialize` to conditionally expand any serialized
// values to their corresponding objects/arrays.
function csv_import_serialized($data, $importer) {
  if (isset($data["meta_data"]) && is_array($data["meta_data"])) {
    foreach (array_keys($data["meta_data"]) as $k) {
      $data["meta_data"][$k]["value"] = maybe_unserialize($data["meta_data"][$k]["value"]);
    }
  }
  return $data;
}

// Hook into the filter
add_filter("woocommerce_product_importer_parsed_data", "csv_import_serialized", 10, 2);
```